# Is it possible to configure everything within context?

Tags: audit.net

I am trying to configure Audit.net and define my custom logic for saving logs.
Is there a way to configure included entities within context?
I tried this
`

```
public ResidentMasterContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
{
   AuditDataProvider = new DynamicDataProvider();
   Mode = AuditOptionMode.OptIn;
   IncludeEntityObjects = true;
   EntitySettings = new Dictionary<Type, EfEntitySettings>
   {
      {typeof(Apartment), new EfEntitySettings()}
   };         
}
```

`
but OnScopeSaving is not firing. And when I change mode to OptOut it takes all entities

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are referring to the Audit.NET EntityFramework extension.

if you use OptIn you need to mark the included entities with `[AuditInclude]` attribute, or use the `Include` methods of the fluent API. You can check the documentation [here](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework/README.md#includeignore-entities-tables).

An example using the fluent API for the EF configuration, to include only the entities *User* and *UserDetail*:

```
Audit.EntityFramework.Configuration.Setup()
    .ForContext<ResidentMasterContext>(config => config
        .IncludeEntityObjects())
    .UseOptIn()
        .Include<User>()
        .Include<UserDetail>();
```

An example of the output configuration:

```
Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup()
    .UseDynamicProvider(_ => _.OnInsertAndReplace(auditEvent =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(auditEvent.ToJson());
    }));
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yeah I have read the documentation but the problem is that I wanted to encapsulate all audit related logic in my context class.

Comment: If you want all your logic there, you could make the initialization calls on the static constructor of your context